# Как поставить Убунту на машину с двумя видео: встроенным и картой?

Tags: установка, видеокарта, linux

Как поставить Убунту на машину с видеокартой, интегрированной в мать и PCI видеокартой? Монитор подключен через PCI видеокарту. Пытаюсь установить Убунту 11.04 с загрузочной флешки. Сначала все хорошо, показывает менюшку, а потом при запуске установки пишет много всего и виснет. Причем если подключить монитор через мать, то все нормально. В БИОСе встроенное видео не отключается, можно только [АВТО] выбрать. Видеокарта GeForce 9600.

Answer (score 1):

Надо в опциях grub поставить видео режим vesa, если после установки будет также, топопробуйте

```
echo "blacklist nouveau" >> /etc/modprobe.d/50-blacklist.conf
```

затем нужно будет установить коммерческие дрова nvidia.